# Sorting List based on another float List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Given two lists below in C#:

```
List<string> X = new List<string>({    "a",    "b",    "c",    "d",    "e",    "f",    "g", "h",  "i"});
List<float>  Y = new List<float> ({ 0.991f, 1.471f, 3.819f, 0.003f, 2.291f, 2.887f, 2.887f,   0, 1.0f});
```

What will be the cleanest/shortest way of sorting X using float values from Y to get the following output?

```
"h", "d", "a", "i", "b", "e", "f", "g", "c"
```

The order for the elements having the same float "key" does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
IEnumerable<string> sorted = X
    .Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
    .OrderBy(o => Y[o.Index])
    .Select(o => o.Value);
```

Basically:

- Use [`.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) to project your List (`X`) into a new sequence of anonymous objects that contains the string from `X` and its index within the list.
- [Order the sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) by the corresponding value in `Y`.
- Select the `Value` portion of the anonymous object to create a new sequence containing just the `string`s from `X`.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZjZvBR

Answer (score 4):

If each string key is unique and each list is perfectly matched, you can use them as keys in a dictionary using zip from System.Reactive.

```
var dic = X.Zip(Y, (k, v) => new { k, v })
          .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

Now, sort your newly formed dictionary by value.

```
var sortedDict = from entry in dic orderby entry.Value ascending select entry;
```

In a "one-liner" using query syntax, this becomes:

```
var dic = X.Zip(Y, (k, v) => new { k, v })
          .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
          .OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: very neat and very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The following code follows the bubble sorting technique...

```
for(int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < max - i; j++)
    {
        if(Y[j] > Y[j + 1])
        {
            int temp = X[j];
            X[j] = X[j + 1];
            X[j + 1] = temp;
            int temp1 = Y[j];
            Y[j] = Y[j + 1];
            Y[j + 1] = temp1;
        }
    }
}
```